# Can I create shared partition for Ubuntu and Windows 10 keep Fast Boot?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 16.04

Have any way help me create shared partition for Ubuntu - Windows 10 and keep Fast Boot of Windows 10 on?

I want to do this because my windows 10 startup very slow if I disable Fast Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use a shared between Windows and Ubuntu NTFS partition and use Fast Boot.

Fast Boot is not a fast boot, Windows is set up to hibernate instead of shutdown. In this case NTFS partitions are left in a state that you can't mount them to Ubuntu with read/write permissions.

You can force this, but it may corrupt data on NTFS partitions.

The only way to use a common NTFS partition with Fast Boot enabled is to mount it to Ubuntu as read-only.